# This submit button is disabled after adding it into a collapse?

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I added this collapse and added a form into that but the submit buttons are not working and sending the data into php file.

```
     <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <h3><strong>Login</strong></h3>
                <p></p>
                <form class="signup-form" action="checklogin.php" method="POST" role="form">
                    <div class="form-input-group">
                        <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i><input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Enter Username" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-input-group">
                        <i class="fa fa-lock"></i><input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter your password" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-input-group">
                            <input type="submit" value="submit" id="submit1" name="submit" class="btn-fill sign-up-btn" style="background-color:#222222;color:#ffffff;">
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
```

Content only relevant to version 1.0.

```
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <h3><strong>Register</strong></h3>
                <p></p>
                <form class="signup-form" action="checkreg.php" method="POST" role="form">
                    <div class="form-input-group">
                        <i class="fa fa-user"></i><input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Choose username" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-input-group">
                        <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i><input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Enter your email" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-input-group">
                        <i class="fa fa-lock"></i><input  type="password" name="password" placeholder="Choose your password" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-input-group">
                        <input type="submit" value="submit" id="submit2" name="submit" class="btn-fill sign-up-btn" style="background-color:#222222;color:#ffffff;">
                    </div>
            </form>

            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <h3><strong>Social Login </strong></h3>
                <p></p>

                    <ul style="list-style:none">
                        <li style="list-style:none"><button class='custom-login fb-login' onclick='fblogin()'><div class='custom-div1'><img src='fb29.png'/></div><div class='custom-div2'>Sign in with Facebook</div></button></li>
                        <li style="list-style:none"><button class='custom-login go-login'><div class='custom-div1'><img src='google.png'/></div><div class='custom-div2'>Sign in with Google+</div></li>

                    </ul>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>




</section>
```

Please help with this... thanks in advance

Comment: what error are you getting in console.log?

Comment: able to create fiddle or snippet ?

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
script.js:14 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).tagit is not a function
ping:1 Application Error: There was a problem getting data for the application you requested. The application may not be valid, or there may be a temporary glitch. Please try again later.
10(index):27 <br />
<b>Parse error</b>:  syntax error, unexpected '$conn' (T_VARIABLE) in <b>/home/bombaybarbell/public_html/checklogin.php</b> on line <b>10</b><br />

Comment: thats the problem that in fiddle it is working

Comment: @PunitGajjar this is working in fiddle

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/4kzcg41t/


@PunitGajjar this is the fiddle\

Comment: how can i show sir @MuhammadIrfan

there are four errors in total

Comment: Check your files on server are they placed properly, your server cannot locate script.js file, make sure script.js is attaced correctly, Thanks

Comment: @MuhammadIrfan 
sir i am not able to get you

Comment: do you have a file named script.js??

Comment: @MuhammadIrfan yeah sir i do have

Comment: then you are not referencing correctly that file in your php file

Comment: @MuhammadIrfan then how can i mention it correctly sir

Comment: @MuhammadIrfan no more error are showing in console now, yet the problem remains

Answer (score 0):

There is a syntax error in your PHP code as per the comments. Fix that first

e application may not be valid, or there may be a temporary glitch. Please try again later. 10(index):27 
 **Parse error**: syntax error, unexpected '$conn' (T_VARIABLE) in

Comment: so will the php file be responsible for the this page before even going to that page ?

Comment: see the error console by clicking F12 dev tools. WHile submission, what error u r getting (or) comment out the Javascript files, you have included and see whether the submission works fine or not.

Comment: solved each and every error, no more error in console now @Senthil

Comment: attach the full html code, JS and CSS if you still seems submission is not working

Comment: i have updated in jsfiddle.net, don't use border: none for submit. So it appears to be disabled. but it is working as expected. Use this CSS changes.

Comment: #submit2, #submit1 {
    border-radius: 16px;
   }
   
   input[type=text],input[type=password] {
    border: none; 
 } i have updated the CSS changes in fiddle, now the click button as per CSSS won't seeems to be like disabled. The click is workign and redirecting as expected.

Comment: i've removed even the border radius ye it is not working and in the fiddle it was working even with the borders

Comment: To drill down the problem, have a simple form . Remove CSS from the page and include of javascript files comment out. Then see, whether the simple form submission happens. Then keep on incrementing your changes. So you will get to know, at which place the form submission is not happening. Because the fiddle code works fine and i am not able to reproduce the issue what you mentioned.